# java, webservice, SOAP, thread and websocket

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websocket, glassfish

I have a java client calling a java SOAP webservice deployed on glassfish server 4.1, that same java client also has a websocket connection to a server deployed on the same server. 
Basically my architecture is this I have a java client calling a SOAP webservice, and connected to a java websocket server endpoint. Why? You can akin this to a bank, the client calls the SOAP webservice for say to check the account balance, then the websocket serves in notifying the client when a credit/debit has been made on the account.
Problem: In my main method I startup connection with the websocket, after that I call the webservice for a resource. Now the problem is I have to try several times before a call to the webservice is made. Its a very strange bug. I tried initializing the websocket on a different thread but I still get the same problem. Please see the code below

**Bank webservice:**

```
//relevant import statements
@WebService(serviceName = "BankService")
public class BankService {
private static final Map<Integer, AccountHolder> accountHolders = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, AccountHolder>();
private static AccountHolder customer, merchant;

public BankService(){
    customer = new AccountHolder("Customer 1", 1234, 4321, 4000, null, null);
    merchant = new AccountHolder("Merchant", 5678, 8765, 1000, null, null);
    accountHolders.put(1234, customer);
    accountHolders.put(5678, merchant);
}

@WebMethod(operationName = "getBalance")
public String getBalance(@WebParam(name = "acctNum") int acctNum) {
    AccountHolder client;
    synchronized(accountHolders){
        client = accountHolders.get(acctNum);            
    }
    return client.toString(); //returns a string containing balance
    }
}
```

**Bank notification websocket:**

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/n")
public class NotificationServer {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        logger.info("Connected ... " + session.getId());        
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void notifyCustomer(String message, Session session) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
    }
    @OnClose....
}
```

**Client**

```
public class Client {
    static Client client;
    private String getBalance(int acctNum) {
        BankService_Service service = new BankWebService.BankService_Service();
        BankService port = service.getBankServicePort();
        return port.getBalance(acctNum);
    }

    private void wsc() throws InterruptedException {
        BankNotificationClient bnc = new BankNotificationClient();
        Thread thread = new Thread(bnc);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        client = new Client();
        client.wsc();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(!"quit".equals(scanner.next())){
            if(scanner.next().equals("check")){
                System.out.println(client.getBalance(1234));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Bank notification client:**

```
//necessary import statements
import javax.*;
import org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager;

@ClientEndpoint
public class BankNotificationClient implements Runnable {
    private static Session clientSession;    
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    ClientManager clientws;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Connected ... " + session.getId());
        clientSession = session;
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        ....
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        logger.info(String.format("Session %s has closed because %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
                client = ClientManager.createClient();
                client.connectToServer(BankNotificationClient.class, new URI("ws://localhost:8080/BankService/n"));
                System.out.println("working" + client.getClass());
            } catch (DeploymentException | URISyntaxException e) {
                logger.info("Something has gone wrong initializing the socket");
            } 
    }
}
```

I am using netbeans 8.0.2 as my development IDE. Having deployed the webservice and websocket to glassfish server 4.1. Running this would give the following output
**Output:**

```
Aug 05, 2015 11:31:18 PM BankNotificationHandler.BankNotificationClient     onOpen
INFO: Connected ... 981de7b4-91b9-43b6-beaf-c219500ee77a
check
check
Dear Customer Customer 1, your account balance is 4000.
check
check
Dear Customer Customer 1, your account balance is 4000.
check
check
Dear Customer Customer 1, your account balance is 4000.
```

As you can see from the output I have to type and enter "check" twice before I get a result from the webservice. Using a debugger on the first entry of check the code suddenly halts at the if statement in the while loop, then I have to enter "check" again. On entering check it continues from where it stopped in the if statement line and proceeds to give me the desired result.

Please let me know if there is any other information I have left out. 
Cheers.